# How to do dynamic queries on MySQL from Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, meteor

I have been trying to make dynamic queries against MySQL from Meteor using the numtel:mysql package. So far it's not successful. Perhaps I either need to know how to pass a dynamic argument to the subscribe, or need to know how to get the result of liveDb.select as an array or object rather than a cursor (liveDb is instantiated by called new LiveMysql(...)). I have tried doing the query in a method on the server side (as declared in Meteor.methods(...), and the method does not return the result. If anyone has code examples for this, that would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is helpful links for use Meteor with MySQL for select query, execute stored procedure,user mongo like publish subscribe method as well as join query in publish.

1. [MySql:numtel package](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql)
2. [Leaderboard MySql example](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql-leaderboard)

   // The below code reference from  [Leaderboard MySql example](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql-leaderboard)

   ```
    Meteor.publish('allPlayers', function() {
   return liveDb.select(
   'SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY score DESC',
   [ { table: 'players' } ]
   );
   });
   Meteor.publish('playerScore', function(name) {
   return liveDb.select(
   'SELECT id, score FROM players WHERE name = ' + liveDb.db.escape(name),
   [
   {
   table: 'players',
   condition: function(row, newRow, rowDeleted) {
   // newRow provided on UPDATE query events
   return row.name === name || (newRow && newRow.name === name);
   }
   }
   ]
   );

   Meteor.methods({
   'incScore': function(id, amount) {
   check(id, Number);
   check(amount, Number);
   liveDb.db.query(
   'UPDATE players SET score = score + ? WHERE id = ?', [ amount, id ]);
   }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call change on your MysqlSubscription with the same params as defined in the Meteor.publish.

In my case:

```
    export const mySqlSubscription = new MysqlSubscription('tableName');

    Meteor.publish('tableName', function(filters){
        var filterString = buildFilterString(filters);

        var qString = 'SELECT ..... FROM tableName '+filterString;

        //console.log(qString);

        return liveDb.select( qString, [ { table: 'tableName' } ] );            
        }
    );
```

Then whenever I want to update my subscription for a different filter I call:

```
    mySqlSubscription.change(this.getReactively('filterRecord'));
```